# TCP/IP Modbus (Master/slave communication)

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, ip, modbus

Is it necessary to use internet for TCP/IP modbus communication?

Actually, I want to make a Master and slave connection between my two Pcs using ethernet (LAN).

Answer (score 0):

Modbus TCP can be used in the local network and that's actually the most common case. Putting it on the public internet instead would be insecure. The communication protocol TCP/IP is also used in the LAN and not only on the public internet.

Comment: Actually I want to do Mod bus TCP/IP communication between my Programmable Automation controller (PAC) and IO cards via ethernet in such a way that controller will act like a master and IO cards will act like a slave. Could you please explain this code to me? I will be very thankful to you.